# JS scripts loading in a random order

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a simple website which loads a number of js files.  It looks like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="1.js"></script>
        <script src="2.js"></script>
        <script src="3.js"></script>
        <script src="4.js"></script>
        <script src="5.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Each js file looks like this:

```
console.log("Loading 1.js");
```

With the "1" replaced by the correct number.

I expect that the console will look like this:

```
Loading 1.js
Loading 2.js
Loading 3.js
Loading 4.js
Loading 5.js
```

Sometimes it does.  However, sometimes it looks like this:

```
Loading 1.js
Loading 3.js
Loading 4.js
Loading 5.js
Loading 2.js
```

Why is this?

I've attempted to fix this with `defer` and `async`, but they don't seem to have any effect.

Working with my real files (not just the minimal example), it seems that longer files are consistently loaded later.  The earliest I've seen the longest file load (~200 lines) is 4th out of 9 (and it's supposed to load then) but it's appeared in every position past that.  Similarly, the shortest file (16 lines) is expected to load 5th and I've observed it to load 1st through 5th.

How can I ensure that my files load in the order that I want them to?

Comment: That sounds odd. They *should* load in their order in the DOM, unless they have the `async` attribute (which might be nondeterministic, not sure)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah, that's what I thought too. That's why I asked.

Comment: I resolved this by putting the script tags right before </body>, but I'd still like an answer, if possible.

Comment: I tried it myself but couldn't reproduce the problem. Do you have a live site that has this issue? What you're describing really shouldn't happen, web developers can depend on a higher script to have run before a lower script starts. It sounds likely that there's something else at play (like an asynchronous action) that isn't in the question

Comment: Nope; that's literally all I had. :(

Answer (score -1):

Another technique you can use, is to append each script to the body only on the completion of its previous script.

```html
something like...
  
           <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
           <html>
              <head>
                <script src="1.js"></script>
              </head>
            </html>
```

then script 1.js will then contain
`let secondScript = document.createElement("script");`
`secondScript.setAttribute("src", "2.js");`
`document.body.appendChild(secondScript);`

then script 2.js will then contain
`let thirdScript = document.createElement("script");`
`secondScript.setAttribute("src", "3.js");`
`document.body.appendChild(thirdScript);`

then script 3.js will then contain
`let fouthScript = document.createElement("script");`
`secondScript.setAttribute("src", "4.js");`
`document.body.appendChild(forthScript);`

then script 4.js will then contain
`let fifthScript = document.createElement("script");`
`secondScript.setAttribute("src", "5.js");`
`document.body.appendChild(fifthScript);`

you can decide to use "await" to implement document.body.appendchild(......)

I hope solve's your bug...